# error extracting some characters using 'gsub'

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to extract some kind of key between a comment. This is what i've tried:

```
x<-c("0000169/2020", " 00038/01-2020 para la busqueda y localizacion d", "037/01-2020  coment",
     00076/01-2020  se añ")
x2<-gsub("{0,1}[0-9]{4}(\\ {1,}.*)", "", x)
```

This is the result:

```
x2 
c("0000169/2020", " 00038/01-", "037/01-",00076/01-")
```

This is what i want:

```
c("0000169/2020", " 00038/01-2020", "037/01-2020",00076/01-2020")
```

How can i eliminate durplus text without elimiate alos part of the code i've been trying to isolate?
It must be the part after the code because code patterns are sliglthly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use something like this?

```
sub("(\\d+/\\d+(-\\d+)?).*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "0000169/2020"   " 00038/01-2020" "037/01-2020"    "00076/01-2020"
```

This extracts a number followed by `"/"`, followed by another number with an optional `"-"` and a number.

The same pattern can be used in `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
stringr::str_extract(x, "\\d+/\\d+(-\\d+)?")
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code did the work. Only one questiion. Do you know why mine didn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your code. I am not exactly clear on what it is doing.